# Is there a standardized approach to creating information web pages to accompany an ontology?

Tags: rdf, owl, semantic-web

A lot of ontologies have URLs which provide detailed information on the defined classes and properties. For example the prefixes: http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/ or http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/ . I have noticed a lot of variation in the way these sites are published and I am wondering if there is a standardized, automated approach to generating information webpages from an ontology (.owl) or are these generally created manually by the ontology author?

Comment: There is no standard in this regard. Every site does its own thing. You can have a look at the [OBO foundary](http://www.obofoundry.org/) that aims to standardize biomedical ontologies. Even with the standardization efforts there, the individual sites are not covered. Hence, every site is still very much created individually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure there is a standardized way to do this, but there is a few tools frequently used to document your ontology :

- [Parrot](https://labs.mondeca.com/parrot/parrot) is a Java tool which I find is providing a pretty nice output. You can use the online instance or use the CLI tool (the code lives at https://github.com/dayures/parrot now I guess). This example is generated with `parrot` : http://www.ontotext.com/proton/protonext.html.
- [Ontospy](http://lambdamusic.github.io/Ontospy/#generating-ontology-documentation) is a Python library and a CLI tool allowing to generate documentation for your ontology. This example is generated with `ontospy` : https://ontology.phunware.com/ontodocs/.
- [Widoco](https://github.com/dgarijo/Widoco) is a Java tool (CLI or GUI) notably allowing to generate documentation for an ontology. This example is generated by `Widoco` : https://www.isibang.ac.in/~bisu/MOD_ontology/index_en.html.

Answer (score 0):

There are efforts to provide guidance towards standardized metadata for data sets, considering an ontology as at least a data set is a step in the right direction (albeit not automated in any way to my knowledge).

https://www.w3.org/2001/sw/hcls/notes/hcls-dataset/